# How to create an object based matrix in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I need to create a group of person's relationship matrix as following

| x | Joe | Alice | Linda |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | -1 | 4 | 3 |
| Alice | 2 | -1 | 3 |
| Linda | 3 | 3 | -1 |

Using arraylists or MultiDimensional array is kinda confusing to looping and calculating to me, as I have to create another pair to bind each array index to the person's object. just wondering if there's any better way to access/modify values in such matrix structure, tks

Edit:
To be more clear, I'm wondering if there's any existing libraries to help making such matrix easier, my main issue to use multiDimensional arr[row,col], then bind it with Person's list requires some additional works to structure it properly. If something like [Joe,Alice], [Linda, Joe] out of box would make my life easier, lol
at last, it is my C# skill to be blamed :(

Comment: To declare a MultiDimensional Array you could use `int[,] data` or an array of arrays `int[][] data`. You also have the possibility to instance an `List<T>` where `T` is a type for a class.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking to do. In the end, everything stored in memory is an array. Classes just add a simplified method to access said memory; if you don't like what is already available, you can make a class to translate input value(s) to access desired memory.